# php-fpm processes increase drastically

Tags: nginx, webserver, cpu-usage, php

we've seen that some time, under no heavy traffic, the php-fpm processes under nginx start to increase drastically.
We have 35 processes and them all of a sudden, you see CPU at 100% with 160 processes running at the same time. Last time it happened was a few seconds ago, the second last one was 2 weeks ago, pretty weird. We do not see memory problems or anything strange (too many accesses or so on).

Do you have any idea how we can avoid creating those processes? Or what could be the cause?

Comment: This question will perform better on server fault. Have you tried decreasing number of max_children and pm.starts_server.

Answer (score 1):

well fpm probably creates them to handle the traffic, and if the process has 100% then that might be some part of ur code eating up the processor.

If you want to force fpm not to create more than a certain number then check the file under `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, there you'll find max children and stuff like that

Comment: The tricky thing is that you dont see any difference in traffic, and it happens randomly, rarely but randomly. When we have a lots of visits CPU spikes up and we usually add a machine, then it's  fine, but this problems happens without any traffic increase.

Comment: Maybe there's a certain URL that eats up the processor, and someone keeps hitting it, so a new child is created to handle it, but keeps working without finishing